# jQuery assigning a class to a grid item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i found jQuery code that prints out the div that is clicked inside a grid, how can i modify this code so that it adds class ".active" only to the div .grid_item that has been clicked, can somebody help me understand how to do this?

I have added the html and js down below.

```js
$(".grid").click(function(event) {
  var hoveredGridItems = $(this).children()
    .filter(function() { return $(this).is(":hover"); });
  
  if (hoveredGridItems.length > 0)
    console.log(hoveredGridItems[0]);
  else
    console.log("no element detected!");
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* styles just for demo */
.grid__item {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  
  /* styles for centering text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">One</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Two</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Three</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Four</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Five</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Six</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Seven</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Eight</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Nine</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Like this : `$(".grid .grid__item ").click(function(event) {$(this).siblings().removeClass("active");$(this).toggleClass("active"); console.log($(this)[0]);})` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".grid__item").click(function(event) {
    $(".grid__item").removeClass("active");
    $(event.currentTarget).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* styles just for demo */
.grid__item {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  
  /* styles for centering text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grid__item.active {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">One</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Two</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Three</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Four</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Five</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Six</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Seven</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Eight</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Nine</div>
</div>
```

Easiest way is to set an event handler on the individual "grid__item", not on the whole grid (rather than using the hover method which is a bit overly complex).

Then you can use the currentTarget of the event to get the item clicked to add the class. I also, before that, remove that active class from all the grid items so only the most recently clicked gets the class.